# Finding document_root through commands in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I see my document_root host via PHPMyAdmin?
Is there a sql command for this?
[PHP/MySQL]
I didn't find anything in phpmyadmin variables. I tried several commands but it didn't solve my problem. Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't access through commands in phpMyAdmin but you can find the document_root directory of your web server by the following methods:

1. Create a PHP script and write this `<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>` and run it on your server.
2. If you have access to the command line on your server, you can use commands like **httpd -V** for Apache or **nginx -V** for Nginx to get information about the server configuration, including the **DocumentRoot**.